# Download Docusign clickwrap agreement without oauth

Tags: php, docusignapi, clickwrap

I succesfully make my customer sign an elastictemplate contract on my website using the docusign given js code  in docusign backoffice

```
<script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"></script>
<script>
docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({  xxxxxx})
<script>
```

My customers don't need a docusign account for agree the contract
Now, how can i generate the link so that the customer can download the signed contract later

my customer

I saw in the docusign documentation a call to
`/clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/agreements/{agreementId}/download`
But this need to ask docusign API for a token. I don't want that for my customers

Any help will be apreciate

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

If you use [JWT for authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), then your customer doesn't need to log in. They can all impersonate the one user that you choose to use as the primary user/account for API calls.
All SDKs support using JWT, you can do that PHP as well. See example for PHP auth code for JWT - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/JWTConsoleApp/JWTConsoleApp.php (you can also download this as a quickstart from https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/)

Note that this is for eSign API, but Click API just requires additional scopes, the rest is the same. If you use the [Click PHP SDK](https://packagist.org/packages/docusign/click-client) then even the call you mentioned can be done from PHP directly. See example for this in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/Click/GetClickwrapResponseService.php